# Was the Prophet Muhammad buried facing Mecca?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Context:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24236487#24236487

> Depending on the orientation of his body in his grave (was he buried? I don't know the relevant history and/or religious texts) and the position of his grave relative to Norway, isn't it possible that anything mean in that country would be said behind his back?

I've researched this and according to https://www.everplans.com/articles/muslim-funeral-traditions, Muslims are usually buried facing Mecca. Given that the burial place of the Prophet is roughly between Mecca and Norway, if he was buried facing Mecca, he would have his back turned to Norway.

Blasphemous implications aside, was the Prophet Muhammad buried facing Mecca?

Comment: I have no idea if this is blasphemy or not according to Islamic law and customs. If it is blasphemous, I'm still very much interested in the answer, so I hope the blasphemy can be edited out without touching the core of the question.

Comment: Burying a person on his right side facing Mecca isn't part of Islamic customs.  The Prophet Mohammed never told us to do that and it's not mentioned in the Quran.

Comment: @Sayyid According to https://www.everplans.com/articles/muslim-funeral-traditions, Muslims are usually buried facing Mecca. I might be mistaken, so I'll edit the question to clarify it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Muslim scholars unanimously agree to bury the deceased person facing Kaaba (Qiblah) in Makkah. Hence it is believed that Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) is also facing Qiblah.

e.g.

http://alfatihoun.edaama.org/Fatawas/English/Fatawas/V3/Two2a.htm

http://www.inter-islam.org/Actions/Part10.html#The%20Shar%27ee%20method%20of%20Dafn%20%28burial%29

islamqa.info/en/7076

sunnahonline.com/library/fiqh-and-sunnah/276-funerals-according-to-the-quran-and-sunnah#h21-the-burial

Comment: Adding related parts from your references to your answer could be better. also you can use add link tool to add links. This way your answer looks better.